# How to return the content in .txt I chose in the GUI to the variable in main program(using PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made a GUI program by PyQt to choose a .txt file and I want to return the content to a variable in the main.py for further execution of the main function. Here is my code

**main.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openai import OpenAI

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import sys, UI

def process_file_content(content):
    print("File content:", content)

class myMainWindow(QMainWindow, UI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = myMainWindow()
    window.file_content_signal.connect(process_file_content)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    # I want to save the content to a variable here
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**UI.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    file_content_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-80, 10, 861, 561))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 30, 191, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("微軟正黑體")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("微軟正黑體")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 140, 93, 28))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("微軟正黑體")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.chooseFile_button_clicked)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 170, 261, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("微軟正黑體")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.fileContent = None
        self.file_test = None
        self.fileChosen = False
        #self.fileContent_changed.connect(self.get_fileContent)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "main"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please choose file (.txt)"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "choose"))
    
    def chooseFile_button_clicked(self):
        filePath = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter='TXT (*.txt)')
        if filePath:
            file = open(filePath[0],'r')      
            self.fileContent = file.read()             
            file.close()                   
            self.file_content_signal.emit(self.fileContent)  # Emit signal with file content



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now I can only use the process_file_content(content) to print the content I choose in terminal.
I have tried many ways to save the content in a variable in the main function.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Simplify your example to be minimally reproducible. No need to include the stuff that are not relevant

Comment: It will help to know what you're actually going to do with that variable, and if that window is going to be the ***only*** window that your program will ever show. Because if it's not, you cannot just quit the QApplication. Not to mention the fact that calling `sys.exit()` will instantly close the Python interpreter as soon as `app.exec()` returns (usually, when the last window is closed). Finally, pyuic generated files should ***NEVER*** be edited. Everything you manually added to `Ui_MainWindow` should actually be in `myMainWindow`.

Comment: The variable will be a text string and I will pass this variable to chatGPT and ask it to analyze the content and generate the outline for me.
Btw this is the only window.

Comment: @YenTingChen Then you need to *store* the value of the line edit in the instance so that you can retrieve it after the application has quit (you can only use real python functions after a widget has been destroyed, which is what happens when the application quits). As said, you **must** consider the above aspects: 1. `sys.exit()` quits the Python interpreter, so you cannot use it there; just call `app.exec()`; 2. you should **not** edit pyuic generated files; see the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).